# Enforce request Accept-Type and Content-Type to JSON only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-api

I would like to enforce all request `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers to JSON only whatever the client asked for. And, of course, always respond with JSON !

I tried with the following `respond_to` and `before_action` filters :

```
respond_to :json

before_action { headers["Content-Type"] = Mime::JSON.to_s }
before_action { request.format = 'json' }
```

But when I try to do a `POST` request on my `login` route, with no `Accept` and `Content-Type`, the concerned controller still processes the request as `*/*`. And if the user set another `Content-Type`, for example `application/html`, it still uses this `Content-Type` instead of `application/json`.

```
Started POST "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-14 10:05:16 +0200
Processing by V1::AuthenticationsController#create as */*
ActionController::ParameterMissing(param is missing or the value is empty: user):
```

Is there a way to do that without too much dirty hacks ?

Thank you,

M.

Answer (score 3):

You can restrict the content type via a before_filter like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    before_filter :restrict_content_type

    private
    def restrict_content_type
        render json: {msg:  'Content-Type must be application/json'}, status: 406 unless request.content_type == 'application/json'
    end
end
```